# How to increment counter in for loop? (Pascal)

Tags: for-loop, increment, pascal

I have a big issue because this piece of code was compiling correctly in Dev-Pascal but not in Lazarus.

```
 for k:=1 to n do
     begin
          writeln(a[k]:4:2,'  ',a[k+1]:4:2,'  ',a[k+2]:4:2);
          inc(k,2);
     end;
```

I'm getting this message

> Error: Illegal assignment to for-loop variable "k"

What I should do now? I need this solutions (incrementing k counter) in my program.

Comment: What about `for k := 0 to n div 3 - 1 do begin writeln(a[k * 3 + 1]:4:2, '  ', a[k * 3 + 2],  ... `? That is what I would do, if I had to access 3 elements on each iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I think it is more a case of Dev-Pascal letting you get away with it whereas quite rightly FP does not. The reason that the compiler will not usually let you modify the `for` variable within the loop is that it can subvert the code the compiler generates to determine when the upper `for` value has been reached.

Add a local variable `j`, assign it the same starting value as `k`, increment it by 2 inside the `for` loop and use `j` as your array indexer instead of `k`.

Comment: "increment it by 2 inside" - sorry, I don't get it. Can you explain that thing?

Comment: `Inc(j, 2)` or `j := j + 2`

Comment: Thanks! But finally I do this with repeat loop.
`k:=1; repeat writeln(a[k]:4:2,'  ',a[k+1]:4:2,'  ',a[k+2]:4:2); inc(k,3); until k>=n;`

Answer (score 0):

Delphi does not allow modification of the loop variable, TP does.   In its own modes FPC follows Delphi because that is the sane thing to do because of the reasons that MartynA listed frustrate optimization.

However **FPC does allow it** in Turbo Pascal mode for old codebases, add {$mode tp} or compile with -Mtp

Comment: TP didn't, AFAIK. At least the latest versions (TP7, TP6, TPW1.5, etc.) didn't.